# How to play the videos from other channel automatically when the video of previous channel is finished in youtube view in android app

Tags: android, video, youtube-api, android-youtube-api, autoplay

I have 3 channels suppose channel A, channel B, Channel C. Each channel has 10 videos. when I click on channel A it plays all the videos one by one. when the last video i.e the 10th video is finished playing I want the videos of Channel B to play automatically and then if the all the videos of channel B is finished playing the videos of channel C will be played automatically. And again the videos of channel A will be played. This will continue in the loop.
How to achieve this by using youtube API in android app. Any help or code snippet will be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to experiment with [PlayerEventListener](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlaylistEventListener) from youtube player api docs.

Comment: I have used  onPlaylistEnded() method.It is redirecting to the 1st video of the playlist but it is stopping there. It is not playing 2nd,3rd videos continuously.Inside the  onPlaylistEnded() method I have used loadVideos(Playlist) method where "playlist" is an arraylist with all the video ID's.